# How to get the day component out of an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I have an NSDate object and need an integer of the day. i.e. if we have 25th May 2010, the int should be 25. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that an NSDate is just a timestamp and only has a "day" when considered with respect to a given calendar and time zone. If you want the Gregorian calendar in the current time zone,

```
NSTimeZone * tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
CFAbsoluteTime at = CFDateGetAbsoluteTime((CFDateRef)date);
int day = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(at, (CFTimeZoneRef)tz).day;
```

If you want the UTC day, set `tz = nil`.

Also, CFAbsoluteTime and NSDate are (as far as I know) based on POSIX time which specifies a 86400-second day, and thus do not handle leap seconds.

Comment: The best answer will be for the current time zone.

Comment: @Altaveron That's not necessarily true. For example, in a unit test you'd want to specify an explicit timezone instead of accessing global state.

Answer (score 17):

Please consider [this post](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/getting-day-of-the-week-from-nsdate.html) on how to get calendar components from an `NSDate`. Essentially it will look something like:

```
NSCalendar*       calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:myDate];
NSInteger         day = [components day];
```

(Don't forget memory management for the above.)

Comment: This is the way to do this. Not creating date formatters and other madness.

Comment: This seems to be so clearly what OP wanted and yet not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you only need the "25" part of an NSDate you can get it from a dateFormatter.

Something like:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayInMonthStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
int dayInMonth = [dayInMonthStr intValue];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"Today is the %i. day of the month", dayInMonth);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "EEEE" as the format for full name of the day.

Use "EEE" as the format for the short name of the day.

Example :

```
- (NSString *)getDayOfTheWeek:(NSDate *)date{
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] ;
     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
     NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
     return formattedDateString;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem a while back, and I created the following methods to make everything easier.

---

**Definitions**

```
#define DATE_TYPE_hhmmss [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"h", @"m", @"s", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYY [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M", @"D", @"Y", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYYhhmmss [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M", @"D", @"Y", @"h", @"m", @"s", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYYWWhhmmss [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M", @"D", @"Y", @"W", @"h", @"m", @"s", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYYhhmmssWW [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"M", @"D", @"Y", @"h", @"m", @"s", @"W", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_YYYYMMDD [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Y", @"M", @"D", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_YYYYMMDDhhmmss [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Y", @"M", @"D", @"h", @"m", @"s", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_YYYYMMDDWWhhmmss [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Y", @"M", @"D", @"W", @"h", @"m", @"s", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_YYYYMMDDhhmmssWW [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Y", @"M", @"D", @"h", @"m", @"s", @"W", nil]
#define DATE_TYPE_FRIENDLY [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xx", nil]
```

**Date Methods**

*Create Date From Values*

```
-(NSDate *) getDateWithMonth:(int)month day:(int)day year:(int)year {
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [dateComponents setMonth:month];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD"];
    [dateComponents setDay:day];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    [dateComponents setYear:year];

    NSDate * result = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    return result;
}

-(NSDate *) getDateWithMonth:(int)month day:(int)day year:(int)year hour:(int)hour minute:(int)minute {
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [dateComponents setMonth:month];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD"];
    [dateComponents setDay:day];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    [dateComponents setYear:year];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    [dateComponents setHour:hour];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [dateComponents setMinute:minute];

    NSDate * result = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    return result;
}

-(NSDate *) getDateWithMonth:(int)month day:(int)day year:(int)year hour:(int)hour minute:(int)minute second:(int)second {
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [dateComponents setMonth:month];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD"];
    [dateComponents setDay:day];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    [dateComponents setYear:year];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    [dateComponents setHour:hour];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    [dateComponents setMinute:minute];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"SS"];
    [dateComponents setSecond:second];

    NSDate * result = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    return result;
}
```

*Get String From Date*

```
-(NSString *) getStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date dateType:(NSArray *)dateType {
    NSString * result = @"";

    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSString * format = @"";

    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

    NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
    NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
    NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];
    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];

    if (dateType != nil) {
        for (int x = 0; x < [dateType count]; x++) {
            if (x == ([dateType count]-1)) {
                if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", year];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", month];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"D"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", day];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", weekday];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"h"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", hour];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"m"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", minute];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"s"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", second];
                }
            } else {
                if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", year];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", month];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"D"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", day];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", weekday];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"h"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", hour];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"m"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", minute];
                } else if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"s"]) {
                    format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", second];
                }
            }

            if ([[dateType objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"xx"]) {
                format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Year: %d, Month: %d, Day: %d, Weekday: %d, Hour: %d, Minute: %d, Second: %d", year, month, day, weekday, hour, minute, second];
            }
        }
    } else {
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", year];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", month];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", day];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", weekday];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", hour];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", minute];
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d|", second];

        format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d", year, month, day, weekday, hour, minute, second];
    }

    result = format;

    return result;
}
```

---

**Example**

```
NSDate * date = [self getDateWithMonth:12 day:24 year:1994];
NSString * dateInString = [self getStringFromDate:date dateType:DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYY];

int month = [[[dateInString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int day = [[[dateInString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
int year = [[[dateInString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

NSLog(@"String of Date: \"%@\"", dateInString);
NSLog(@"Month: %d", month);
NSLog(@"Day: %d", day);
NSLog(@"Year: %d", year);
```

The method `[self getDateWithMonth:12 day:24 year:1994]` returns an `NSDate` object which is usually hard to read, so you can use `[self getStringFromDate:date dateType:DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYY]` to get a string of an `NSDate` object.

Use the definitions (macros) to specify the format of the date you would like to get in the string.

For example:
`DATE_TYPE_hhmmss` would return the `Hour|Minute|Second`,
`DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYY` would return the `Month|Day|Year`,
`DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYYhhmmss` would return the `Month|Day|Year|Hour|Minute|Second`,
`DATE_TYPE_MMDDYYYYWWhhmmss` would return the `Month|Day|Year|Weekday (#)|Hour|Minute|Second`

and so on...

**Console Log**

```
2012-04-29 13:42:15.791 Atomic Class[1373:f803] String of Date: "12|24|1994"
2012-04-29 13:42:15.793 Atomic Class[1373:f803] Month: 12
2012-04-29 13:42:15.794 Atomic Class[1373:f803] Day: 24
2012-04-29 13:42:15.794 Atomic Class[1373:f803] Year: 1994
```